# Pass data from UIViewController to UISpiltView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

Right now I am facing some problem to pass data from UIViewController to UISpiltViewController.
   My app start with UIViewController, and after user login it, there is a segue from UIViewController to UISpiltViewController, UISpiltViewController is root view of a NavigationViewController, and this NavigationViewController is a root view of a TableViewController. I have written a class for this TableViewController, called MasterView, and right now I want to pass some information from loginView to this MasterView.

```
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
```

But I want to know how to write the prepareforsegue function.

```
   override func  prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "login"
    {
        let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController).topViewController as MasterViewController

        controller.authorityNum = self.authorityArray
    }

}
```

I want to pass an array, but I will get class cast error. Please help me with this.

Comment: Is it possible to show you storyboard screen ?

Comment: I think your segue.destinationViewController should be casted as MasterViewController not UINavigationController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this i am not sure but i think your segue is **Model segue** so

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "login"
    {
        var splitView:UISplitViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UISplitViewController
        var controller = splitView.viewControllers.first?.topViewController as! MasterViewController
        controller.authorityNum = self.authorityArray
    }
}
```

***Try to NSLog every line it may help***

Answer (score 0):

Like this,

```
let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MasterViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 of the accepted answer.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "login" {
            let splitView:UISplitViewController = segue.destination as! UISplitViewController
            let navController = splitView.viewControllers.first as! UINavigationController
            let controller = navController?.topViewController as! MasterViewController
            controller.authorityNum = self.authorityArray
    }
}
```